# Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'PublishingWeb' - Could not find file

Tags: upgrade, publishing

I'm upgrading SharePoint 2007 to 2010 using attach and upgrade method.

When running database upgrade a series of similar errors are shown in upgrade log (could not find some temp file with an unpronounceable name).

> Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'PublishingSite' (Id: 'f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa') in Site 'http://intranet10'. Exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  (Inner Exception: Could not find file 'C:\Users\farmadminuser\AppData\Local\Temp\z-jynvy2.dll'.)
>
> Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'PublishingWeb' (Id: '94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb') in Web 'http://intranet10'. Exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  (Inner Exception: Could not find file 'C:\Users\farmadminuser\AppData\Local\Temp\3ldfh-oo.dll'.)

Can anybody shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always, always, always run your ps shell as administrator.

Comment: "Every day's a school day with SharePoint" :)

Comment: Not every time it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to forcefully activate publishing features from %HIVE%/template/features/*.xml by means of **stsadm** to work around this error.